# How to insert polygon with hole in WKT (well known text) format into postgis table?

Tags: postgresql, polygon, postgis

I have a table in postgis, which has 4 columns: ID, name, the_geom, SRID. I need to write an SQL query which will insert this exterior polygon (Element 1) in the table named "woods", ID = 44, the name of that exterior polygon is "oak", and SRID is "4412".

The coordinate values for Element 1 and Element 2 (the hole):
Element 1= [P1(6,15), P2(10,10), P3(20,10), P4(25,15), P5(25,35), P6(19,40),
    P7(11,40), P8(6,25), P1(6,15)]
Element 2= [H1(12,15),  H2(15,24)]

Here is the image:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A85337_01/sdo_objb.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ST_MakePolygon`:

- http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_MakePolygon.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use [geometry constructor](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch07.html#Geometry_Constructors) function ST_[GeomFromText](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html)

```
INSERT INTO woods (ID, name, SRID, geom)
VALUES (44, 'oak', 4326,
ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((6 15, 10 10, 20 10, 25 15, 25 35, 19 40, 11 40, 6 25, 6 15))',
     4326))
```

with example of SRID equal to [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)